# magittr pipe does not correctly pass a connection

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm pulling in a `.rda` file and loading the data.  It works fine like this:

```
library(magrittr)
conn <- "http://www.mosaic-web.org/go/datasets/DCF/MeasTreatTables.rda" 
  %>% url()
load(conn)
```

But when I use the pipe throughout:

```
"http://www.mosaic-web.org/go/datasets/DCF/MeasTreatTables.rda" %>% 
  url() %>% 
  load()
```

Nothing is loaded into the Global Environment.  Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when using `magrittr` command chains you're not operating in the global environment.

Let's run your command, but returning the environment by the same token:

```
library(magrittr)
rm(list=ls())
parallel_universe <- "http://www.mosaic-web.org/go/datasets/DCF/MeasTreatTables.rda" %>% 
   url() %>%
  {load(.);environment()}
```

Now let's explore those environments:

```
ls()
#[1] "parallel_universe"
ls(parallel_universe)
#[1] "Measurements" "Treatments"
```

We've been populating the wrong space. Now let's try again :

```
rm(list=ls())
"http://www.mosaic-web.org/go/datasets/DCF/MeasTreatTables.rda" %>% 
url() %>% load(globalenv())
ls()
# [1] "Measurements" "Treatments"
```

Tada

Note that you cannot assign to `parent.frame()`, it won't work, because `magrittr` is nesting environments, so if you really want to use this outside of the global environment, this will work:

```
my_env <- environment()
"http://www.mosaic-web.org/go/datasets/DCF/MeasTreatTables.rda" %>% 
url() %>% load(my_env)
```

See also : [Assigning to temp variables inside of `maggritr` command chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409397/assigning-to-temp-variables-inside-of-maggritr-command-chain/46431805#46431805)

Comment: Aha!  And so when one evaluates a name in the parallel environment (e.g., `eval(substitute(Treatments), envir = parallel_universe)`) one gets the data frame of that name.  Nice!  Thanks much, @Moody_Mudskipper.

Comment: Just `eval(Treatments,envir = parallel_universe)` will do :) , or `get("Treatments",envir = parallel_universe)`

Comment: Actually, the first one doesn't work.  Objects 'Treatments' won't be found.